# Android - Server Socket

Tags: android, sockets, emulation, port

I have few question regarding Socket Communication in Android.

1)I have developed server socket app for android that listens to port 8888.

a) When i host my server on the emulator I'm unable to communicate to it through Client   application that I have on my PC since both (Emulator & Client) app are on my laptop & on the same network i think that they should be able to communicate with each other.

b) When i deploy the same server app on my android mobile device and try to communicate it through the same Client Application that I have on my PC, the client application gives a timeout exception as its unable to communicate to it.

My first question is How can i test server/client socket app with Emulator & 1 android device? Can i even use my PC's client socket application to test my server socket?

**I have Client Socket Application for my other application so theres no problem with the client application.

2) My second question is to test my server app on the android device do I have to forward the desired port?
   a) For Emulator: How can I forward port?
   b) For Device: How can i forward port?
   c) Can i forward port programmatically?

**Just for Information:

I'm using Eclipse as android developement tool.

** MY Server Code as there can also be problem with my server socket code too.

```
Socket socket = null;
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try
        {  
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            System.out.println("Listening :" + SERVERPORT);
            System.out.println("Server IP:" + SERVERIP);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());                   
                String str = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("message Received: " + str);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {                   
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
            finally
            {
                if( socket!= null)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        socket.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if( dataInputStream!= null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        dataInputStream.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }                   
                if( dataOutputStream!= null)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        dataOutputStream.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Edited:**
A very interesting part is that if i set port to 8080 PC's Client Socket App do connect to Android App on my android device but i don't receive socket on my server nor the data I send. Nothing happens after the link => **socket = serversocket.accept();**

Also I have set the permission in the manifest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your first question, on how to access the network from the emulator: the emulator runs on its own network address space, isolated from your PC. You have to configure network redirection to access devices on your network.

See more details in https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html

Comment: Ok that worked for me, Now only question left is how can i run this same server on my android device?

Comment: Not sure I followed the question. Do you mean you scenario 1b above? If so, it should work fine, assuming the PC is trying to connect via the port exposed to the network (the one configured for forwarding).

Comment: yes only question left unanswered is regarding android device. When i forward the port on Emulator it can communicate with the PC's Socket device but I do know how to make that PC's client application communicate with Android app deployed on the android device.

Comment: Make sure you are using the redirected port on the client application. Beyond that, there is no big secret. You can also try two other things: 1) test your client/server application entirely on the PC (run the Java code on the PC - not on Android) to make sure it's not a coding problem unrelated to Android and 2) run Wireshark (google and download) to see where exactly the connection fails (e.g. the client application sends a TCP SYN, but get no ACK or there isn't even a SYN from the application).

Comment: I didn't redirect any port from my android device, That's what i'm asking actually how can i do that?

Comment: It's right at the beginning of the link I put in the answer. See the part that explains what `redir add tcp:5000:6000` does. It basically takes port 5000 on your PC IP address and forwards to the emulator IP address 6000. So your client application will talk to the PC address and port 6000, while your server socket on the device is listening on port 5000.

Comment: ok...my scenario have changed I have changed that Socket Server to WebServer now I can query that webserver in emulator from browser after forwarding that port from adb. but If i deploy that same app on my android device I can't query that same webserver from browser. How can i do that

Comment: Is your device connected via Wi-Fi in a corporate network? If so, you won't be able to. The device would have to go via a proxy to access the Internet, but Android doesn't support a proxy yet. Switch to 3G or go to a network that doesn't have a proxy (your home network will do). Beyond that, you will have to be more specific, i.e. post the code and where it fails (any error, exception or other indication of failure you are getting). Since you are going into a different direction you might as well post as a separate question as well.

Comment: Also I'm not talking about accessing internet, have you seen "Sharekeyboard" http://mayakovskij.posterous.com/link-your-desktops-keyboard-to-your-android-p, In this app you can use you PC's keyboard to write text on your android app like (messaging app, chat etc) thats what I'm trying to do

Comment: It lets you access your app using your PC's browser whose accessing app on a specific port to write data

Comment: My code is this: http://codersapprentice.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-integrate-jetty-server-in-my.html

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I was able to run the server on my device and was able to query it from my PC's browser but after forwarding port for my specified device using ADB using the serial number. Now my question is do I have to forward any port if my client is one android device and server is another android device?

Comment: There is no need to forward the ports when one client is talking to the other. You only need to forward the port if they are in separate networks and there is no router between those networks. That's the case for the emulator, which run on its own, separate network. For two devices in the same network they can talk to each other directly, given their IP and port.

Comment: Link is broken which is why they shouldn't be used as an answer.

Comment: @Seth: Fixed the link, pointing to the new page. Thanks for letting me know. I understand the risk with links. However, the instructions and nuances around them aren't that simple. I'd have to replicate the entire page here to make it useful. The link will have to do in this case.

Answer (score 10):

have you set the right permission inside your Manifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

is needet to setup sockets

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the question and answers. It helps me figure out the narrow path towards my working combination.

The procedure turned out to be trickier than we expected. The socket client side has to use "127.0.0.1", instead of "192.168.0.15" or "10.0.2.15", to connect to the Android emulator on the same computer. The following are 6 steps I tried and works.

Step 0: Go to terminal

Step 1: find out port of Android emulator console using adb, Android Debug Bridge (in my case the port is 5554)
/Users/zhijunsheng/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
List of devices attached
9357cefb device
emulator-5554 device

Step 2: retrieve auth_token of Android emulator console
cat /Users/<my_home_dir>/.emulator_console_auth_token
sncfmfC+Lg9OtAT4

Step 3: connect to Android emulator console
telnet localhost 5554
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
OK

Step 4: authenticate
auth sncfmfC+Lg9OtAT4

Step 5: add the redirection instruction
redir add tcp:50000:50001

I also have [a video in YouTube](https://youtu.be/HkcEqOD8OZw) recording what I tried.