# connect my local PC to ANDROID device using Wi-Fi

Tags: java, android, tcp, wifi

I am working on one android app. I want to connect my local PC to ANDROID device using Wi-Fi(Local).

just like this [APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en).

I am new to network programming.

Anyone help me to do this some architecture or example or code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Server-Client architecture. Depending on what you want to do you could either set up a server in the phone and have a client on the computer that will connect to the phone. Or the other way around, server on the computer and let the phone connect to it.

Here is another thread that have some example code (there is a lot of other examples and tutorials):
[Android - Server Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455016/android-server-socket)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way around this except by hard work. You are expected to read the documentation and work through the examples. There are heaps of tutorials on Programming on Android on the 'Net. Use them.

Comment: please see this app i want to do something like these but only for local area network: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en